# Enabling and Disabling Elitism during a Genetic Run

Tags: genetic-programming, epochx

In EpochX framework how do you enable and disable Elitism during a run? Is there a way to configure the framework to function like that.

Answer (score 0):

According the [oficial documentation](https://www.epochx.org/guide-algorithm.php):

> the "Elitism - is performed by the *ElitismManager*, and the number of
> elites is obtained from the model's getNoElites() method [...]  The
> **number of elites requested may be zero**, which effectively **disables elitism**.

So, you can set zero to the *getNoElites* function to disable elitism.